# dplyr case_when does not return expected result when using multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to mutate a new column, `id` based on the match using a case when. When a match is found add an ID value, if not leave it NA. This works well when I have fewer columns in the `case_when` test. But, when I'm using multiple columns the output is not as expected. Below is a reproducible example

```r
set.seed(10)
library(dplyr)
values <- c(0, 1)
country <- c("USA", "Germany","UK","Russia","China")
role <- c("admin", "developer","UI designer","HR","manager")
Df <- dplyr::tibble(
  cname = sample(country, 10, replace = TRUE),
  role = sample(role, 10, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE),
  d = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE),
  e = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE),
  f = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE),
  g = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
Df
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   cname   role            b     c     d     e     f     g
   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 China   manager         0     0     1     0     1     1
 2 UK      developer       0     1     1     1     1     0
 3 USA     developer       0     0     0     0     1     0
 4 Germany HR              1     0     0     0     1     0
 5 UK      developer       0     1     1     1     0     0
 6 Germany admin           1     1     1     1     1     0
 7 Germany UI designer     1     0     0     1     0     0
 8 UK      HR              1     0     1     0     1     1
 9 USA     HR              1     0     1     0     1     1
10 China   manager         0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Need an id for each department column.
`b = 1, c = 2, d =3, e = 4, f = 5, g = 6`
Expected output . I have removed the other columns, but it is OK if we retain the columns with 0,1 values as well

```
cname   role    Department  Departmet_id
China   manager     d         3
China   manager     f         5
China   manager     g         6
UK      developer   c         2
UK      developer   d         3
UK      developer   e         4
UK      developer   f         5
UK      developer   g         6
USA     developer   f         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `case_when` is only going to return one value. Where do you expect ID to be—multiple columns, or a list of vectors? Aside from that, I know this is often my suggestion, but you're probably better off reshaping this to a long format, checking which columns are 1, then reshaping back rather than manually checking 20 columns and trying to collapse them all together in some way

Comment: I was expecting to get the result in a single column, may be multiple columns and merging also works. How should I approach this with reshape ? Can you share an example ?

Comment: Those 3 outcomes are pretty different though. It's unclear what exactly you want as the output—I think you'll have to pick one

Comment: @camille, updated the Q, to simplify with current output and expected output. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Still based on camille's comment:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(cname, role), 
               names_to = "Departement",
               values_to = "Departement_ID") %>% 
  group_by(cname, role, Departement) %>% 
  summarise(Departement_ID = ifelse(any(Departement_ID == 1), 
                           which(names(df) == unique(Departement)) - 2, 
                           NA_integer_)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 28 x 4
# Groups:   cname, role [8]
   cname   role      Departement Departement_ID
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>                <dbl>
 1 China   developer d                        3
 2 China   developer e                        4
 3 China   developer f                        5
 4 Germany HR        b                        1
 5 Germany HR        c                        2
 6 Germany manager   b                        1
 7 Germany manager   c                        2
 8 Germany manager   d                        3
 9 Germany manager   e                        4
10 Germany manager   f                        5
11 Russia  manager   b                        1
12 Russia  manager   d                        3
13 UK      admin     b                        1
14 UK      admin     c                        2
15 UK      admin     e                        4
16 UK      admin     f                        5
17 UK      admin     g                        6
18 UK      developer b                        1
19 UK      developer c                        2
20 UK      developer d                        3
21 UK      developer f                        5
22 UK      manager   b                        1
23 UK      manager   c                        2
24 UK      manager   d                        3
25 UK      manager   e                        4
26 UK      manager   f                        5
27 USA     manager   e                        4
28 USA     manager   g                        6
```

#### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(cname = c("UK", "USA", "Germany", "Russia", "UK", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "China", "UK"), role = c("developer", 
"manager", "manager", "manager", "admin", "HR", "developer", 
"manager", "developer", "manager"), b = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1), c = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), d = c(1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), e = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), f = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), g = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Hi, updated the Q, to simplify with current output and expected output. Hope this helps. Your solution probably works, how to include only specific column to pivot wider.

Comment: why are you doing `-2` at summarize ? I was able to replicate until that step on real data. Wondering if there is an easier way to match the columns ?

Comment: Because the `b` column starts at position 3 and I shift it to 1.

Comment: thought so, how do I address when the columns which that we are avoiding `pivot_longer` are in between those columns that need to be pivot longer. The above solution assumption is that after 2nd columns everything else is to be pivoted. I can update the Q, if required ?

Comment: I'm using it like this `columns_to_pivot <- colnames(Df)[grepl(pattern = "^(?:b|c|d|e|f|g)$", x = colnames(Df))]` to get the vector name. How do I incorporate this ?

Comment: the issue with the output you have is in case of `Germany | manager | b ` The value is 0 and not 1, however, the output you have assigns it a Department ID. Same for the case of `Germany | manager | e `. Both of these should not have a department_id instead just show NA

Comment: Not sure why, but just `germany | manager`  has that issue

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you want the position of each letter in the alphabet, here is a solution that I thought:

```
library(tidyverse)
Df %>% 
  #Pivot data to make a single column with all letters
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(cname,role)) %>% 
  # Apply function for each
  rowwise() %>% 
  # Create an id, where the number it is the position of the alphabet of each letter - 1
  mutate(id = which(str_detect(letters,name))-1 )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, updated the Q, to simplify with current output and expected output. Hope this helps.

Comment: This works on the example , but I guess you are using `letters` which is an inbuilt base R. I had letters as a column name just for an example, in reality they have specific names. So, unable to replicate on real data